# Performance profiling a .net website with shared,remote hosting

Tags: .net, performance, profiling, shared-hosting

Having performance issues with my website. I'm relatively new to .net, although I've learned an awful lot over the last few months!

I posted this question last night

[Improving performance when working on Images with ASP.NET in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066700/improving-performance-when-working-on-images-with-asp-net-in-vb)

From which a comment was posted which got me thinking, and Googling this morning.

I'm unclear on how I would actually got about 'performance profiling' my site.

I've seen that there are tools built into visual studio if I can replicate the entire site locally, but I can't do that. There are also tools in iis, and this:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/index-2?utm_expid=53846-2&source=products-a-page&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.red-gate.com%2Fproducts%2F

I like the look of the screen shots on the link above, it seems intuitive and easy to understand.

What I am totally unclear on though is, does require direct access to the actual server machine? Or, is it a .net plugin which I can use remotely.

I need this facility because the site is hosted on a shared server which I do not have direct access to.

If this isn't the case, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about finding bottlenecks in my code, remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way I know is to install FireBug for Mozilla Firefox and take a look at the net tab while the page is loading. This displays a clear timeline of server calls and loading time taken. https://getfirebug.com/

Taking a quick look at your site with Firebug shows each image taking nearly a second to load for me. It could be that your ISP is just slow, who are you hosting with?

Comment: Thanks Oli, yes, the net tab in Firebug is helpful, but I wanted to go deeper really. Rather than profiling page calls, to profile individual functions so I can see if any particular server functions are running slow. Turns out it can't be done unless I have full control of the server, aside from saving time stamps in a database at start and end of certain functions.